# PostgreSQL UPDATE FROM

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, temp-tables

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, I'm afraid I need a little more clarification/brushing up on the UPDATE FROM clause in PostgreSQL.

Basically I have a temporary table with some intermediary computed stuff that I want to use to update the main table. This temporary table includes two foreign keys and a score, such as:

```
score   fk_offer    fk_searchprofile
65      1764        12345
...
```

I tested the rows to be updated with a select (the table `temp_offerids_with_score` contains the offers that need to be updated):

```
SELECT s.pkid, tmp.fk_offer, s.fk_category, tmp.score, tmp.fk_searchprofile
FROM 
            temp_weighted_scores_offers AS tmp
            INNER JOIN sc_sp_o_c_score AS s
            ON tmp.fk_offer = s.fk_offer
WHERE 
            tmp.fk_offer IN (SELECT fk_offer FROM temp_offerids_with_score)
            AND 
            s.fk_category = 1
            AND s.fk_searchprofile = 12345;
```

This correctly returns the expected number of rows (in this case 10):

```
pkid    fk_offer    fk_category  score  fk_searchprofile
1       47          1            78     12345
2       137         1            64     12345
3       247         1            50     12345
...
```

However, if I use the same in an UPDATE FROM:

```
UPDATE sc_sp_o_c_score
      SET score = tmp.score
FROM 
            temp_weighted_scores_offers AS tmp
            INNER JOIN sc_sp_o_c_score AS s
            ON tmp.fk_offer = s.fk_offer
WHERE 
            tmp.fk_offer IN (SELECT fk_offer FROM temp_offerids_with_score)
            AND 
            s.fk_category = 1
            AND s.fk_searchprofile = 12345;
```

the whole table, over 32000 rows, gets updated with the same (wrong, of course) score overall.

```
pkid    fk_offer    fk_searchprofile    fk_category score
1       47          12345               1           104 
2       137         12345               1           104
3       247         12345               1           104
```

What am I missing?

Thanks, Julian

**EDIT:** just in case this could be of any help - for the record, I'm migrating things from SQL Server here, where this is in fact a valid construct.

Comment: (From the manual)[http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html]: "*Note that the target table must **not** appear in the from_list, **unless you intend a self-join***"

Comment: yes, but: "(in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_list)", which I am doing with **AS s** if I'm correct

Comment: So you ***do*** intend a self-join of the table with itself? You don't do that in the select query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the table to be updated also as a self-join (through reference in the `FROM` clause). Take that out and you should be good:

```
UPDATE sc_sp_o_c_score
  SET score = tmp.score
  FROM temp_weighted_scores_offers AS tmp
  WHERE tmp.fk_offer = fk_offer
    AND tmp.fk_offer IN (SELECT fk_offer FROM temp_offerids_with_score)
    AND fk_category = 1
    AND fk_searchprofile = 12345;
```